# I'll make "all my effort" to do that - acceptable idiom?

Tags: sentence-construction

If I say:

> I'll make "**all my effort**" to come on the time"

Is it considered an acceptable / correct English?

Comment: "I'll **give** all my effort to come on time." 'all my effort' is okay but I think, "I'll do **my best** to come on time" would be better.

Answer (score 14):

No, but we might use the phrase "every effort":

> "I will make **every effort** to be there on time."

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not!

> I'll **try my best** to be on time.
>      I'm going to try to come on time.

Never use "on the time" like that.

Answer (score 3):

In order to discover if this is acceptable/correct English, let's break it down into small phrases:

> I'll make

Good so far. What are you making?

> all my effort

This is strange. This claims that you have a pile of effort, and you can take from and add to it, and you're talking about the entire pile. Alone, this is a good analogy. However, when we look at these together:

> I'll make all my effort

This says that you are starting with zero effort in your pile, and you're going to make all of it. That doesn't make much sense. A better alternative is `use` or `give` instead of `make`.

Let's move on to the rest of the sentence:

> to come

Alight, that's okay. To where are you coming?

> on the time

Here's where it gets silly. This makes it seem like you're starting where you are, and your destination is "the time". Also, "to come on" has a rare, but lewd definition (see [Wiktionary's 5<sup>th</sup> verb definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come#Verb)), so you shouldn't say you come *on* something.

So what is a good alternative to `to come on the time`? Well, let's go back. `to come` was fine, and I asked "To where are you coming?". Let's answer that with `in`. "Where are you coming?" "I'm coming in!"

Now I can ask "When are you coming in?", and you can answer with `on time`, meaning that when you come in, it will be at the correct time.

Putting it all together, **here's what you probably want to say:**

> I'll give all my effort to come in on time.

Perfect! You've got a pile of effort, and you're giving all of it in your attempt to go from where you are to here at the correct time.

Answer (score 2):

No.

A better way to say it would be

> 'I will **do my best** to be on time'

Answer (score 1):

You could also use "best efforts"

"I'll make best efforts to come on time"
or
"I'll make my best efforts to come on time"

Comment: How do you explain 0 results of this example - on Google?

Comment: Best efforts is a great answer.  All over google!

Comment: @Dory http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/best+effort It's obviously not unheard of. As a native English speaker, I assure you "best effort" is a common phrase. Although seeing it in the plural strikes me as a little strange.

Comment: @jpmc26 I know what you mean about "best efforts" over "best effort". I've heard both and was trying to decide which one was more correct. I think grammatically they're probably both interchangeable; I feel like I've heard "best efforts" more often than "best effort" in my experience.